# most efficient way to delete an entire binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I would like to know the most efficient way to delete an entire binary search tree. also not to let any memory leak so having to check if all the nodes in the sub trees are deleted first.

I cant think of any efficient way besides post order traversal, deleting as you go. any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set your root node as `null`. Let the garbage collector to do its job.

Comment: besides that what would be the best way. i am aware I can do that.

Comment: Define "best."  If deleting the root node causes all descendant nodes to be garbage collected, what could be better than that?

Comment: fastest, and most efficient,  or would all their time complexities just be O(h) or the height of the tree?

Comment: Deleting the root node is O(1).

Comment: @user1730008 in languages like C and C++, you have to free the memory by yourself, using any traversal algorithm will do. In Java, the garbage collector will free the memory for you, so setting the root node as `null` will tell the JVM "Hey! I won't use this structure at all, so you can clean it when you want."

Comment: @user1730008 in Java, this method is O(1). You're not in C/C++ languages. Just remember that.

Comment: @user1730008 you're welcome. Don't forget to click the check next to the post to mark it as the answer. You could do it after 15 minutes since you post the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  I specified that I would like to know the most efficient one if I have to check all the subtrees and leaves before deleting the root node. that is why I asked this. I understand its the most efficient, i really wanted to know which traversal would be the fastest I shouldve specified.

Comment: @user1730008 This *is* the best way. Nothing else you invent can come close. All proper traversals of a binary tree are O(N): there is nothing to choose between them on that ground.

Answer (score 1):

[Deleting all leaves from a binary tree](http://www.coderanch.com/t/528481/java/java/Deleting-all-leaves-binary-tree) thread discusses about deleting all children of binary tree.

```
public static void deleteLeaves(BSTNode root) {  
  if (root == null)  
    return;  

  if (root.left != null && isLeaf(root.left))  
    root.left = null;  
  else  
    deleteLeaves(root.left);  

  if (root.right != null && isLeaf(root.right))  
    root.right = null;  
  else  
    deleteLeaves(root.right);  
}
```

How ever simplest will be set root node to `null` and let garbage collector do its job which will be `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` in above case..

Comment: This method will be O(n), when n = number of elements in the tree. By setting `treeRoot = null`, it will be O(1), as per the Java GC algorithm.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have mentioned that as the best way. :) He wanted something else.

Comment: Yes, but it's good to add the difference between both methods :).

Comment: A B-tree is not a binary tree.