# What is the best way to clear a BST for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, binary-search-tree

I want to clear a BST so as to take advantage of the garbage collector. So, to clear a BST, is it sufficient to set the root to null, so that I end up with a bunch of abandoned nodes with no pointers to them? Or is it better to set each node to null?

1. Are the two methods equivalent?
2. Would one of them cause memory leak?
3. Would one be garbage collected faster than the other?

I am also concerned about weak reference and strong reference, etc.

Comment: Neither should be necessary, as long as the BST becomes unreachable. What you're proposing is the opposite of taking advantage of the garbage collector; it's the kind of manual memory management garbage collectors are supposed to avoid.

Comment: TreeMap is the BST (red-black tree) implementation in java. Set the BST map reference to null, to get it garbage collected. It's hard to predict how exactly GC collects each object in the map.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `set the root to null` ? If setting all references that keep track of your BST to null, then yes, it is sufficient to trigger GC. Not sure about performance though, you can test it I guess.

Comment: Terse, but correct, duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12853118/102937).  It is sufficient to set the root to null.  The entire tree becomes unreachable, and therefore eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @user2357112 so are you saying that all I have to do to clear a BST instance is to set the instance itself to null? such as `BST bst= new BST(); ...; bst=null;` and that I don't even need to set the root itself to null? But what I want to do is clear the BST: as in `final BST bst=new BST(); bst.clear();`

Comment: @KatedralPillon: `bst = null` would do fine, and even that won't be necessary if the `bst` variable goes out of scope.

Comment: @KatedralPillon: Or are you talking about removing all elements from the BST and then continuing to use it, adding new elements? In that case, it'd probably look something like `root = null`, depending on how your BST is structured. Frequently, it'd be better to replace it with a new BST, though; for example, if you have `BST bst = new BST();` at the start of a loop body, you'll be working with a fresh BST every iteration, and the old ones will be GC'ed as long as they're not still needed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object that cannot be reached by any live thread will be eligible for garbage collection.

Based on that:

1. Yes.
2. No.
3. Depends on the implementation of GC. Anyway, as a Java programmer, you can't control it. All you can do is have a trust that it will do its job just fine. Also, setting root to null is O(1), while nulling all references is O(n), where n is the number of nodes.

Conclusion:

Just set the root to null and let GC to traverse the tree in the good moment for him :)